# SQLConnection.Open(); throwing exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

Updating an old piece of software but in order to maintain backward compatibility I need to connect to a .mdb (access) database.

I am using the following connection but keep getting an exception, why?

I have validated the path, database existence etc. and that is all correct.

```
            string Server = "localhost";
            string Database = drive + "\\btc2\\state\\states.mdb";
            string Username = "";
            string Password = "Lhotse";

            string ConnectionString = "Data Source = " + Server + ";" +
                                      "Initial Catalog = " + Database + ";" + 
                                      "User Id = '';" + 
                                      "Password = " + Password + ";";

            SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection();

            try
            {
                SQLConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
                SQLConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                // Try to close the connection
                if (SQLConnection != null)
                    SQLConnection.Dispose();

                //
                //can't connect
                //

                // Stop here
                return false;
            }
```

The exception message is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Of course, sorry David.  It is above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly makes you think that a SQL Server connection (SqlConnection) will be willing to connect to an MDB Access database???

If you connect to Access, use [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28VS.71%29.aspx). For Access connection strings, see http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Comment: According to this, Remus you were first with the correct answer... thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a data provider to your connection string:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;

Comment: Is SQLConnection correct as well or should it be OLEDB connection as here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: SQLConnection is fine,  just need the correct provider.  I edited ths connection string for .net

Comment: Yes you could use OleDbConnection.  I am so used to using sqlServer.

Comment: Actually SqlConnection class is only for SQL Server connections. To connect to OleDb providers, use OleDbConnection. SqlConnection will not work.

Comment: Yep, you are totally right, I'm going to go with Joe in that I am so used to using sqlServer connections at work that I totally forgot about an Access database being anything different...

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try this more safer version using the `using` clause...as for the `Database` variable, it would be better and safer to use the `System.IO.Path.Combine` method...:

```
            string Server = "localhost";
            string Database = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\", @"\btc2\state\states.mdb");

            string Username = "";
            string Password = "Lhotse";

            string ConnectionString = "Data Source = " + Server + ";" +
                                      "Initial Catalog = " + Database + ";" + 
                                      "User Id = '';" + 
                                      "Password = " + Password + ";";
            bool bDatabaseOk = false;
            using (SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection()){

                try
                {
                    SQLConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
                    SQLConnection.Open();
                    bDatabaseOk = true;
                }
                catch (SqlException Ex)
                {
                   // Handle the SqlException here....
                   //
                   //can't connect
                    bDatabaseOk = false;
                }
            } 
            return bDatabaseOk;
```

Comment: Originally when the question was posted...I was thinking that the problem was in the connection, so I wrapped it up using the using clause and used a more safer means of IO.Path.Combine....and changed the Exception to SqlException to get the exact error!

Comment: thanks tommie I will take a look and keep this 'safer' way of doing it in mind.