# Proper way to connect to a local .mdb file using SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, sqldatareader

The connection always times out without generating an error message even though it is within trycatch. I suspect there is something wrong with the connection string. This is what I currently have:

```
            string path = @"C:\PATH\TO\wantedDB.mdb";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("File found."); // File is found, so nothing wrong with that.

            string connectionstring = "Database=wantedDB;AttachDBFilename=" +
            path + ";Server=(local)";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opening connection...");
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection opened."); // Program never gets here.
```

I have also tried a relational path in connection string like:

```
string connectionstring = "Database=wantedDB;AttachDBFilename=\"wantedDB.mdb\";Server=(local)";
```

The db is not protected by a password. I have MS Access installed, does that affect this somehow? What am I missing?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Any errors messages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLConnection.Open(); throwing exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398628/sqlconnection-open-throwing-exception)

Comment: I edited the beginning of the question.

Comment: The answer is basically: You can't use `SqlConnection` as this is for connecting to MS SqlServer.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks. I'll keep looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to a mdb file you should use the OLEDB connector:

```
var con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=C:\\wantedDB.mdb;");
```